# Dealing with Laravel routing without htaccess mod_rewrite capability

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, routes

So, currently, I do not have the ability to utilize .htaccess, I have no control over the server config at the moment, so I have to live with /index.php/ in my URL. That's not a problem, but there is one issue.

If I go to `webserver.com/site/index.php` everything works fine. But, if I go to `webserver.com/site/` (without index.php) the site loads but all the links are broken (relative to /site/ instead of /site/index.php/).

I've tried various ways to build the links with url() and route() but I can't get anything to work short of hard-coding the full url for every link.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about redirect to site/index.php if there is just site/

Comment: Do you mean redirect with laravel? I can redirect "/" to "index.php" which works.. but then I end up with /site/index.php/index.php

Comment: In index.php you can figure out if you are on /site/ or /site/index.php and eventually send headers for 301 Moved pernamently with correct location.

Comment: ALL request must be pointed to index.php, without rewrite you can't do it. So there no solution for your issue

Comment: @KmasterYC I realize that. the issue is if you hit the root of the site without index.php it loads index.php but doesn't actually put it in the url, and all urls are then relative to that base url without index.php. If index.php is explicitally in the url then everything is relative to index.php instead (desired result).